# How to get format strings from ngLocale

Tags: angularjs, locale, angularjs-filter

Is there a possibility to get format strings from the ngLocale module?
I need this strings for an own filter which works with moment.js-objects and moment-timezone.

For example in en-us the "short"-String is "M/d/yy h:mm a",
for de-de it is "dd.MM.yy HH:mm" ...

Is there any way to get this strings without the "date"-Filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `$locale` service for this. While the only *documented* API of this service is `$location.id`, the actual service is just a JavaScript object coming from the locale file, ex.: https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/i18n/angular-locale_en-us.js

Using your example, you could get access to the short data format string by injecting the `$locale` service and doing: `$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.short`.

Check the mentioned locale file to see what other locale-specific values are available. And yes, I agree that those are very useful in custom filters / directives.